# How to "wait" for a response from Azure before executing next line in a PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm executing the following in Azure PowerShell

```
Write-Host 'Currently available Azure Subscriptions are: '
Get-AzureSubscription | Sort SubscriptionName | Select SubscriptionName
Write-Host '----------------------------------------------'
```

However the code is printing the "--------------------------" line before the list of Subscriptions.
Is there a way to "block" or "wait" for completion of execution of the `Get-AzureSubscription` command before executing `Write-Host` in the next line?

Comment: That makes no sense since `Get-AzureSubscription` isn't asynchronous. Which API version do you use? ARM or ASM?

Comment: I have tested this in both ARM and ASM. Same outcome. API version 0.9.6

Comment: Can you please write `cls` before the Write-Host 'Currently avail...' to ensure the command line is cleared and check it again?

Comment: Yes, same outcome. It goes:                                                      Currently available Azure Subscriptions are:

----------------------------------------------
SubscriptionName
----------------                                                                                                 Visual Studio Premium with MSDN

Comment: Try to expand SubscriptionName: `Get-AzureSubscription | Sort SubscriptionName | Select -expand SubscriptionName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `Format-Table` at the end of the `Get-AzureSubscription` line and the order of printing was then corrected. I think that while `Get-AzureSubscription` is not asynchronous, maybe the `Sort` and `Select` functions **are** asynchronous, so by adding a non-asynchronous call at the end thru `Format-Table` I got the desired effect.
This is my best guess as to why, I can't be sure this is why this worked though.
So the new script as follows prints the items in order:

```
Write-Host 'Currently available Azure Subscriptions are: '
Get-AzureSubscription | Sort SubscriptionName | Select SubscriptionName | Format-Table
Write-Host '----------------------------------------------'
```

And outputs:

```
All available Azure Subscriptions are:

SubscriptionName
---------------- 
Visual Studio Premium with MSDN
--------------------------------------------- 
PS C:\Users\nissan\Documents\Azure>
```